# My ajax request submits once, then twice, then 4 times and keeps doubling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have tabs with next and previous buttons on the bottom, when I first load the page ajaxloads data in to tab one, when I click next that form will submit fine, but if I press previous after pressing next it'll pull another ajax to populate the first dive the same way I was doing it on load, but when I click next to submit the form, the ajax request doubles and submits twice, then 4 times 8 etc, how can I stop this from happeing.... my jquery on one of my pages which is the same on all:

```
$(document).on("click",".previous", function()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>wizzard/personal_information',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            $('#tab2').html('');
            $('#tab2').removeClass('active');
            $('.tab_2').removeClass('active');
            $('#tab1').html(data);
            $('#tab1').addClass('active');
            $('.tab_1').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});

$(document).on("click",".next", function()
{
    $('#update_contact_information').on("submit", function()
    {

        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                if(!data.success){
                    $.notify(data.error,{
                        className:'error',
                        clickToHide: true,
                        autoHide: true,
                        globalPosition: 'bottom right'
                    });

                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>wizzard/employment_history',
                        type: 'GET',
                        success: function(data){
                            $('#tab2').removeClass('active');
                            $('.tab_2').removeClass('active');
                            $('#tab2').html('');
                            $('#tab3').html(data);
                            $('#tab3').addClass('active');
                            $('.tab_3').addClass('active');
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    $.notify(data.success,{
                        className:'success',
                        clickToHide: true,
                        autoHide: true,
                        globalPosition: 'bottom right'
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>wizzard/employment_history',
                        type: 'GET',
                        success: function(data){
                            $('#tab2').html('');
                            $('#tab2').removeClass('active');
                            $('.tab_2').removeClass('active');
                            $('#tab3').html(data);
                            $('#tab3').addClass('active');
                            $('.tab_3').addClass('active');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

    $('#update_contact_information').trigger('submit');
});
```

**my tabs:**

```
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="rootwizard">
                <div class="navbar">
                  <div class="navbar-inner">
                    <div class="container">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li class="active tab_1"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo System::translate("Personal information"); ?></a></li>
                    <li class="tab_2"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo System::translate("Contact information"); ?></a></li>
                    <li class="tab_3"><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo System::translate("Employment history"); ?></a></li>
                    <li class="tab_4"><a href="#tab4" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo System::translate("Qualification history"); ?></a></li>
                    <li class="tab_5"><a href="#tab5" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo System::translate("Avatar"); ?></a></li>
                </ul>
                 </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">

                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">

                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">

                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">

                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab5">

                    </div>
                    <ul class="pager wizard">
                        <li class="previous"><a href="javascript:;"><?php echo System::translate("Previous"); ?></a></li>
                        <li class="next"><a href="javascript:;"><?php echo System::translate("Next"); ?></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>  
            </div>
```

**and the initial call:**

```
<script>
$(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>wizzard/personal_information',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            $('#tab1').html(data);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Remove the binding of the submit handler from the click handler.

Comment: But I'd like to submit the form on the click of the next button..

Comment: what does the rest of your HTML look like?  where is "#update_contact_information"?

Comment: Move submit binding outside $(document).on("click",".next", function(){ ... });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In two previous answers people are (correctly) suggesting you to restructure your code in order to avoid registering event handler inside another event handler. Yet, as you don't accept those answers, I suppose this doesn't completely answer the question.

What you want to do is to do is to simply submit the form's content when you click the "next" button. At the same time, this button is not part of the form, therefore just clicking it will not trigger the "submit" event. So you are triggering the event manually.

Now what is strange in your description is that your ajax requests are doubling on every click. Normally with each click you'd have just one more request added. See my fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CuGmr/181/), which is the simplified version of your code.

```
var form = $('form');

$(document).on('click', '.next', function(){
  form.on('submit', function() {//with every click one more handler is registered. Click the "click" link several times to see
      alert('submit fired'); 
      return false;
  });
  form.trigger('submit')
})
```

Thus, the question arises: where do you register your handler with `$(document).on("click",".next", function()`? You need to make sure that this handler is only registered once. For this you can put `alert('registering handler')` just before this line in your code to check.
The correct sequence of registering event handlers is showing in this [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CuGmr/182/). The code is:

```
var form = $('form');

$(document).on('click', '.next', function(){

  form.trigger('submit')
})
form.on('submit', function() {//with every click one more handler is registered. Click the "click" link several times to see
  alert('submit fired'); 
  return false;
});
```

So to proceed can you try what I suggested and let me know the result?

P.S. I'm not sure why you need to trigger form submission at all. For your ajax request you are serializing the form and cancelling initial submission (you `return false`;). Thus I'd recommend to avoid using "submit" events at all, and just to do all the work in the "click" handler.

**UPDATE** (after more information was added in the comment below)

So the second part of the problem is following. With every "next" click you are attaching new event listeners and you are replacing the html of your tabs like this `$('#tab2').html(data);`, and `data` contains not only markup, but also js code that is being executed when you insert it (btw, I didn't know that it works like this, it's nice). I think that what you are **expecting** is that once markup (html) is removed, corresponding event listeners will be removed as well. But in fact it's not the case. Why? Because you are *delegating* your event listening to `document` with the code starting with:

```
$(document).on("click",".next", function()
```

Here `$(document)` is what you are attaching your listener to. Instead of going into details I strongly suggest you to check out [this original jquery explanation of event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

So how do you fix it? There are several different ways. Possibly the simplest one (minimal amount of code editing) is to remove your event listeners before you do `.html(data)`. Another way, also simple, is to write

```
$('.next').on("click", function(),
```

as you've done in qualification_history.php. This way you are attaching events to the element itself, and not to the document. The only thing is that you want to be sure that there is a corresponding DOM element before this code gets executed (so you might put your code *after* the markup).

Comment: Hi, I put my jquery in the individual files, so form 1 in page 1, when I click that I empty the div and load page 2 which has the new binding javascript plus html... I have zipped the files up so you get an idea of how I am doing it; http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=01921842907756977156

Comment: @randommman, I checked out your files and I'm quite sure I got it :)

Comment: @randommman, I've added the explanation at the end of my original answer, this should help. Please let me know if you still experience difficulties with this part. But it's funny that you had doubling of the issue because of the 2 different factors.

Answer (score 8):

You are binding a new submit event to the form every time you click the button, that is why it doubles up. Remove the binding from inside the clickk handler

```
$(document).on("click",".next", function()
{

    $('#update_contact_information').trigger('submit');
});

$(document).on("submit", '#update_contact_information', function()
{

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if(!data.success){
                $.notify(data.error,{
                    className:'error',
                    clickToHide: true,
                    autoHide: true,
                    globalPosition: 'bottom right'
                });

                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>wizzard/employment_history',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#tab2').removeClass('active');
                        $('.tab_2').removeClass('active');
                        $('#tab2').html('');
                        $('#tab3').html(data);
                        $('#tab3').addClass('active');
                        $('.tab_3').addClass('active');
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $.notify(data.success,{
                    className:'success',
                    clickToHide: true,
                    autoHide: true,
                    globalPosition: 'bottom right'
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>wizzard/employment_history',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#tab2').html('');
                        $('#tab2').removeClass('active');
                        $('.tab_2').removeClass('active');
                        $('#tab3').html(data);
                        $('#tab3').addClass('active');
                        $('.tab_3').addClass('active');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Just a clarification looking at @randommman's comment on his OP. `$('#update_contact_information').on("submit", function()` is actually registering an event, not calling it.

Comment: I am not sure what is the purpose of your comment, if you set a submit handler many times on a form the trigger submit(which OP deos), it will call the handler the amount of times you bind it.

Comment: It still seems to be doing it :(

Comment: Apologies, I should have commented as a reply in the OP. I meant to clarify that the OP might have thought that `.on("submit"` would call the submit handler, which I thought was the reason for his reply "But I'd like to submit the form on the click of the next button"

Comment: @Musa, If you think of it, you'll realize that the issue you've mentioned will not lead to *doubling* of the number of requests, it will lead to the incremental increase (so 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, not 1, 2, 4, 8, 16). There is also another factor. See me answer below (especially the update) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the full html of the page involved, there is some guessing in this.  The code in the OP is not structured correctly and has other logic errors.  The problem in a nutshell is that you have defined an event handler to add an event handler.

By putting `$('#update_contact_information').on("submit", function(){...})` inside the handler definition for `$(document).on("click",".next", function(){...})`, you are saying:

Every time I click on the a button with a class of `next`, I want to create a new event handler for my element with the id of `update_contact_information`.  So the first time you click `next`, you define and then trigger `submit`.  The second time you click `next`, there is already an existing handler for the submit, plus you add another.

Because you haven't provided the rest of the HTML and JavaScript involved, it is not clear where your code exists.  There are likely other issues as well.

I would restructure the JavaScript, putting all of the event handlers inside the jQuery on ready function for the page.  This allows you to define your event handlers once, and still make your initial call to load the page.

Something like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".previous", function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo Config::get('
      URL '); ?>wizzard/personal_information',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function(data) {
        $('#tab2').html('');
        $('#tab2').removeClass('active');
        $('.tab_2').removeClass('active');
        $('#tab1').html(data);
        $('#tab1').addClass('active');
        $('.tab_1').addClass('active');
      }
    });
  });

  $('#update_contact_information').on("submit", function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr('action'),
      type: $(this).attr('method'),
      dataType: 'json',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        if (!data.success) {
          $.notify(data.error, {
            className: 'error',
            clickToHide: true,
            autoHide: true,
            globalPosition: 'bottom right'
          });

          $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo Config::get('
            URL '); ?>wizzard/employment_history',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
              $('#tab2').removeClass('active');
              $('.tab_2').removeClass('active');
              $('#tab2').html('');
              $('#tab3').html(data);
              $('#tab3').addClass('active');
              $('.tab_3').addClass('active');
            }
          });
        } else {
          $.notify(data.success, {
            className: 'success',
            clickToHide: true,
            autoHide: true,
            globalPosition: 'bottom right'
          });
          $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo Config::get('
            URL '); ?>wizzard/employment_history',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
              $('#tab2').html('');
              $('#tab2').removeClass('active');
              $('.tab_2').removeClass('active');
              $('#tab3').html(data);
              $('#tab3').addClass('active');
              $('.tab_3').addClass('active');
            }
          });
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".next", function() {
    $('#update_contact_information').trigger('submit');
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo Config::get('
    URL '); ?>wizzard/personal_information',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#tab1').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Depending on the rest of your HTML and JavaScript code for your page, this may or may not work as is for you. I'm providing a fiddle that demonstrates something similar in action.  It is not an exact duplicate of the original post, because the logic that example does not work.  It should be a sufficient starting point for:

1. Solving your existing problem of multiple event bindings
2. Giving you a better place to start for fixing the logic problems in your original examples

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/whipdancer/cgn8rdx8/)

Answer (score 1):

This should **help** with the **order and logic** of your events

```
//bind only when the doc has rendered...
$(document).ready(function() {

    //bind click to and element with class previous
    $(".previous").on("click", function()
    {
        //... previous code
        alert("test me ;-)");
    }

    //bind click to and element with class next
    $(".next").on("click", function()
    {
        //... next code.
        alert("test me ;-)");
    }

}
```

Comment: FYI the reason your code is executing multiple times is cozs you have told it that when you click anywhere you want it to bind the click events, effectively doubling up each time. well your next button submit would be doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that the element witch id is `#update_contact_information` is not exists at the beginning. You want to bind an event on `.next` clicked. So, I suggest you use `$.delegate` to bind event before element shows.
more information see [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).

e.g.

```
$(document).delegate('#update_contact_information','submit', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if(!data.success){
                $.notify(data.error,{
                    className:'error',
                    clickToHide: true,
                    autoHide: true,
                    globalPosition: 'bottom right'
                });

                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>wizzard/employment_history',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#tab2').removeClass('active');
                        $('.tab_2').removeClass('active');
                        $('#tab2').html('');
                        $('#tab3').html(data);
                        $('#tab3').addClass('active');
                        $('.tab_3').addClass('active');
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $.notify(data.success,{
                    className:'success',
                    clickToHide: true,
                    autoHide: true,
                    globalPosition: 'bottom right'
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>wizzard/employment_history',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#tab2').html('');
                        $('#tab2').removeClass('active');
                        $('.tab_2').removeClass('active');
                        $('#tab3').html(data);
                        $('#tab3').addClass('active');
                        $('.tab_3').addClass('active');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment

```
$(document).on("click",".previous", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>wizzard/personal_information',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(data){
            $('#tab2').html('');
            $('#tab2').removeClass('active');
            $('.tab_2').removeClass('active');
            $('#tab1').html(data);
            $('#tab1').addClass('active');
            $('.tab_1').addClass('active');
       }
    });
});

$(document).on("click",".next", function(){
    /* Submit binding code from here moved just after this block. */
    $('#update_contact_information').trigger('submit');
});

/* submit binding code from above block */
$('#update_contact_information').on("submit", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if(!data.success){
                $.notify(data.error,{
                    className:'error',
                    clickToHide: true,
                    autoHide: true,
                    globalPosition: 'bottom right'
                });

                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>wizzard/employment_history',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#tab2').removeClass('active');
                        $('.tab_2').removeClass('active');
                        $('#tab2').html('');
                        $('#tab3').html(data);
                        $('#tab3').addClass('active');
                        $('.tab_3').addClass('active');
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $.notify(data.success,{
                    className:'success',
                    clickToHide: true,
                    autoHide: true,
                    globalPosition: 'bottom right'
                });
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>wizzard/employment_history',
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(data){
                        $('#tab2').html('');
                        $('#tab2').removeClass('active');
                        $('.tab_2').removeClass('active');
                        $('#tab3').html(data);
                        $('#tab3').addClass('active');
                        $('.tab_3').addClass('active');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem was near impossible to google, so I'll add some search terms here:
   Asp.net MVC `Ajax.BeginForm()` causes exponential postbacks after every submit.

I know this question is *not* about MVC, but I couldn't find another question to post the solution to.
Please comment with a link if you do find one.  Thank you.

Solution:
For me I had included the `<script>` tag inside my Partial-View (or the Element of my `UpdateTargetID`).
I think the script was being sent over on every postback and piling up on the client/web browser.
Beats me what the internals of my browser does, but once I **moved the Script outside of the** `Ajax.BeginForm()`, the repeated postbacks/submits stopped.

I should note, this particular script was initiating a submit after a time-interval had passed, which would explain why I hadn't noticed this behavior before with other scripts I had added inside my `UpdateTargetID`.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting double requests for each click and this was slowing down the application for each fetch 
what you are doing was still "acceptable" `#user4655002`

**Request Before restructuring code**

[image: Request Log A.]
you can get rid of this error by looking at the overall layout of your html code.
put the requests out of the body prolly at the  footer.

This worked for my case

It may not be possible to post your whole project on SO but i hope this practical advice helps.

**Request after restructuring code**
[image: Request Log B.]